# Flask Python - AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute '_connection'

Tags: python, flask, cs50

I'm creating a Flask framework, and I'm using `CS50` SQLite module to interact with my SQLite database which stores the users and their usernames and passwords. I also tried using the `sqlite3` module, but I was more familiar with this and it was giving me so many errors.

When I `flask run` the webpage loads, but as I try to log in or even register it gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute '_connection'
```

Here is my code for the register function:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""

    if request.method == "POST":

        # Making sure the user actually typed in something in the fields
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        password_confirm = request.form.get("password_confirm")

        # Ensure user provided username
        if not username:
            return apology("Must provide username", 400)

        # Ensure user provided password
        elif not password:
            return apology("Must provide password", 400)

        # Confirming passwords match
        elif not request.form.get("password") == request.form.get("password_confirm"):
            return apology("Passwords do not match", 400)

        # Hash the password and insert the new user into database
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(password)
        new_user_id = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (:username, :hashed_password)", username=username, hashed_password=hashed_password)

        # Is the username unique?
        if not new_user_id:
            return apology("Username taken", 400)

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = new_user_id
```

And if it helps, my login function:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    """Log user in"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 403)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 403)

        # Query database for username
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username",
                          username=request.form.get("username"))

        # Ensure username exists and password is correct
        if len(rows) != 1 or not check_password_hash(rows[0]["hash"], request.form.get("password")):
            return apology("invalid username and/or password", 403)

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

Comment: Maybe it's a database configuration issue, double-check your database configuration.

Comment: @Md.NahidurRahman do you have any idea how to do that or what I should be looking for?

Comment: If you switched from cs50 to sqlite3 back  to cs50 libraries, are you sure the distro code settings in application.py are intact?

Comment: Hello! I solved it by changing from production to development mode.